# Solving $\lim_{ x \to 0^+} \sqrt{\tan x}^{\sqrt{x}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, indeterminate-forms

The limit to be calculated is:

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+}\sqrt{\tan x}^{\sqrt{x}}$$

I tried:

$$L =\lim_{x \to 0^+}\sqrt{\tan x}^{\sqrt{x}}$$

$$\log L = \lim _{x\to 0^+} \ \ \dfrac{1}{2}\cdot\dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{\frac{1}{\log(\tan x)}}$$

To apply the L'hospital theorem but failed, as it went more complex.

How can we solve this, **with or without** L'Hospital?

Comment: Should it be $x\to 0^+$?

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan I think yes.

Comment: It is not hard to prove $x\le\tan x\le x+\dfrac{x^3}3$ for $x\ge 0.$ You can use these estimates to solve your limit. Good Luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, we have 
$$
\begin{align}\lim_{x\to 0^+}\sqrt{x}\ln\sqrt{\tan x}&=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}\ln(\tan x)\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\ln(\tan x)}{\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}}}\qquad\text{which takes the form } \frac{-\infty}{+\infty}\text{and apply LHR to get}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\frac{\sec^2x}{\tan x}}{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^3}}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\frac{2}{\sin 2x}}{-\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x}}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\bigg[-\sqrt{x}\cdot\frac{2x}{\sin 2x}\bigg]\\
&=-\sqrt{0}\cdot 1=0.
\end{align}$$
Hence, the required limit is 
$$\lim_{x \to 0^+}\sqrt{\tan x}^{\sqrt{x}}=e^{\lim_{x \to 0^+}\ln\sqrt{\tan x}^{\sqrt{x}}}=e^{\lim_{x\to 0^+}\sqrt{x}\ln\sqrt{\tan x}}=e^0=1.$$

Comment: This one is the most comprehend-able atm. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align}
\left(\sqrt{\tan(x)}\right)^{\sqrt{x}}&=e^{\frac12\sqrt{x}\log(\sin(x))-\frac12\sqrt{x}\log(\cos(x))}\\\\
&\underbrace{e^{-\frac12\sqrt{x}\log(\cos(x))}}_{\to 1}\,\underbrace{e^{\frac12\sqrt{x}\log\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)}}_{\to 1}\,\underbrace{e^{\sqrt{x}\log(\sqrt{x})}}_{\to 1}\\\\
\end{align}$$

since we recall that $\lim_{y\to 0}y\log(y)=0$ (i.e., with $y=\sqrt{x}$), which can be shown a variety of ways including application of L'Hospital's Rule.

---

Note that we could have arrived at this result quickly by using asymptotic analysis.

Here $\tan(x)\sim x$ as $x\to 0$.

Then we are evaluating equivalently $\lim_{x\to 0}(\sqrt{x})^{\sqrt{x}}$ which by substitution $x=y^2$ becomes equal to $\lim_{y\to 0}y^y=1$

Comment: I prefer the second version

Comment: @Henry I prefer the efficiency also.  But for those who are not mathematically mature, use of an asymptotic equivalent expression might be unfamiliar and seemingly mysterious as to how to apply it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

For small $x>0,$ we can apply $\ln$ to get

$$0\ge \tag 1 \sqrt x \ln \sqrt {\tan x} = (\sqrt x)/2\cdot \ln\tan x$$

Now $\tan x > x.$ Thus $\ln\tan x > \ln x.$ It follows that

$$\tag 2 0\ge \sqrt x \ln \sqrt {\tan x} \ge \sqrt x/2 \cdot \ln x.$$

Now use the well known limit $\lim_{x\to 0^+} x^p\ln x =0$ for any $p>0$ to see that the limit of the right side of $(2)$ is $0.$ By the squeeze theorem, $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\sqrt x \ln \sqrt {\tan x} =0.$ Exponentiating back shows the limit of interest is $1.$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you know $u^u\to1$ as $u\to0^+$ and ${\tan\theta\over\theta}\to1$ as $\theta\to0$.  Then, by writing $x=4u^2$, we have

$$\sqrt{\tan x}^{\sqrt x}=(\tan(4u^2))^u=4^u(u^u)^2\left(\tan(4u^2)\over4u^2\right)^u\to4^0(1)^2(1)^0=1\quad\text{as }u\text{ (hence also }x)\to0^+$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: write $$e^{\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(\sqrt{\tan(x)}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}}$$
and use L'Hospital

Comment: but the power in denominator goes on diminishing this way too!

Comment: then show it us!

Comment: Its hard to type, but first it gets $$\dfrac{\frac{1}{\tan(x)}\cdot \sec^2(x)}{-\frac{1}{x^{\frac{3}{2}}}}$$

Comment: there is a mistype in your derivative $$(\ln(\sqrt{tan(x)}}))^'=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\tan(x)}}\cdot \frac{1}{2}(\tan(x))^{-1/2}\cdot \frac{1}{\cos^2(x)}$$